# When creating a new object in Core Data WkWebView stops responding (SwiftUI)

Tags: core-data, swiftui, wkwebview

I have WkWebView that is playing YouTube videos. I have put together play/pause functionality, and much more. Currently, I'm trying to implement CoreData and I'm trying to save information about the YT videos that are currently playing like the video title and video ID, and more.

I can save the data and I can also see my saved data also I can delete it. However, I have noticed that when I try to save a video my play/pause button no longer works. I Have traced the problem to my WkWebView actions longer works after saving in CoreData but it does work until I try to save.

The functions playVideo and pauseVideo are called, but it seems that WkWebView no longer responds for some odd reason

So my problem is why does my WkWebView no longer respond?

Here is how I have implemented my WkWebView

```
var webview: WKWebView?
    var videoID: String
    let hardcodedPlaylist: [String] = ["EQIh607kd0Y", "A5kGigZHed4", "MLJyFzdQfK8", "Trfxm0TJwuQ", "nVVr7gJNny8", "XqZsoesa55w"]
    
    func createEmbededHtml(videoID: String, playlist: String) -> String {
            return """
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                   <html>
                   <style>
                       * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
                       html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
                   </style>
                    <body>
                      <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
                      <div id="player" ></div>



                      <script>
                        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                        var tag = document.createElement('script');

                        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
                        //    after the API code downloads.
                        var player;
                        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                          player = new YT.Player('player', {
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            videoId: '\(videoID)',
                            playerVars: {
                               controls: 0,
                               rel: 0,
                               modestbranding: 1,
                               playsinline: 1,
                               enablejsapi: 1,
                               playlist: '\(playlist)'
                           },
                            events: {
                              'onReady': onPlayerReady
                            }
                          });
                        }

                        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
                        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                           player.playVideoAt(1);
                        }

                      </script>
                    </body>
                   </html>
                """
    }
    
    init(web: WKWebView?, videoID: String) {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
        self.webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        self.videoID = videoID
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let embededHtmlString = createEmbededHtml(videoID: videoID, playlist: hardcodedPlaylist.joined(separator: ", "))
        self.webview?.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        webview?.isOpaque = false
        webview?.loadHTMLString(embededHtmlString, baseURL: nil)
        return webview!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        private var webViewModel: WebViewModel
        
        init(_ webViewModel: WebViewModel) {
            self.webViewModel = webViewModel
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("webview has loaded")
            self.webViewModel.didFinishLoading = true
        }
    
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Webview.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(webViewModel)
    }
    
    func playVideo() {
        webview?.evaluateJavaScript("player.playVideo()")
        print("playing...")
    }
    
    func pauseVideo() {
        webview?.evaluateJavaScript("player.pauseVideo()")
        print("pauseing...")
    }
```

This code is in a class named Webview, to show as minimum code as possible I will not show how I call my Webview I do not think it will serve a purpose.

Here is a snippet with the code of my button that is used to save a video, I have also included the code for saveVideo and saveContext

```
Button(action: {
                print("saving button pressed")
                
                let currentIndex = webViewModel.playlistIndex - 1
                saveVideo(videoID: videoIDFetcherInfo.videoIDs[webViewModel.playlistIndex] ,title: videoIDFetcherInfo.videoTitles[currentIndex], thumbnailUrlString: videoIDFetcherInfo.VideoThumbnailsUrl[currentIndex])
}, label: {
                Image(videoSaved.isVideoSaved ? "bookmark-border-filled" : "bookmark-border")
                    .sizeShadowModifier(size: 44, shadowRadius: 12, shadowX: 2, shadowY: 6)
            })

 func saveVideo(videoID: String, title: String, thumbnailUrlString urlString: String) {
        let newVideo = Video(context: managedObjectContext)
        
        newVideo.thumbnailUrlString = urlString
        newVideo.title = title
        newVideo.videoID = videoID
        newVideo.createdAt = Date()
        
        
        print("Saving Video")
        
        saveContext()
    }
    
    func saveContext() {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            //TODO: add alert instead
            print("There was an error saving")
        }
    }
```

After saveVideo is called my button for playing/pausing no longer works but the video is saved and I can see that also the respective function is called inside Webview. **Also I'm developing for iOS 14 and using Xcode 12.3 and only using SwiftUI**